# UWP Fall Creators Update and Mobile app?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

I am having UWP app in the Microsoft Store which supports Mobile and Desktop min version as  10240 and target version 15063. Now I want to update to Fall Creators update with 16299. My Project is a Xamarin.Forms app and I had recently upgraded to .NET Standard 2.0. I learnt that i must use min version as 16299 (Fall Creators Update).
Problem is that Fall Creators Update doesn't support any Mobile application. In order to support older versions of UWP, I must downgrade to .NET Standard 1.4.

- Is there a huge difference between 2.0 and 1.4?
- Will I get performance decrease and lose some good benefits?
- Is there a way to use multiple .NET standard versions within the same solutions like Shared project 2.0, Android 2.0, IOS 2.0, UWP 1.4?

Comment: I'd recommend you split this in two questions. (a) differences between 1.4 and 2.0 and (b) what happens to users that are stuck on 15063. The 3rd one I think only you can answer, based on your app type and target audience. Without that knowledge I don't see how anyone could make a recommendation.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT thanks for your advise. i have just edited my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no performance difference between .NET Standard 1.4 and 2.0 as .NET Standard is just a "blueprint" of what a particular target platform should offer, not the implementation itself, which is provided by the platform. .NET Standard 1.4 has smaller API surface but otherwise most of the time should suit your needs.

Thing to keep in mind however is that many libraries are either transitioning or planning transition to .NET Standard 2.0 (including Xamarin.Forms), which means developers will slowly be forced to upgrade if they want to use the latest and greatest releases. But I fully understand the need to keep support for Windows 10 Mobile, as I have several apps I want to keep there as well.

When you really need to have min version 16299, you can go in the direction of having multiple Git branches for separate releases - one for pre-16299 builds and one with additional features for 16299 and later.

One library cannot do multi-targeting (like act as 2.0 for Android and iOS while being 1.4 for UWP), but you alternatively could create two libraries (2.0 and PCL), develop in 2.0 and then use `Add new item` -> `Add as link` to add a "link" to those files to the PCL library and share them between the two.